# IPv6 not working with Static IPv4 address

Tags: networking, ipv6

Despite interfaces getting IPv6 autoconfiguration addresses with iface ethX inet static in /etc/network/interfaces, IPv6 routing does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to /etc/network/interfaces

```
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```